# Why doesn't a chemical reaction occur with the movement of electrons in the context of electricity?

Tags: electricity, electrons, charge, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

In school it is generally taught that the movement of electrons between two atoms causes a chemical reaction. However, when it comes to electricity why doesn't a chemical reaction occur with the movement of electrons? (I understand that there is a chemical reaction in a battery, but even with situations like static electricity making your hair stand up, there doesn't appear to be any chemical reaction taking place. Why is the latter situation any different than an atom losing electrons during a chemical reaction?)

Comment: Chemical reactions are said to be spontaneous (naturally occuring) when the Gibbs Free energy is negative. In the case of electrolysis and electrolytic cells the reverse of the spontaneous reaction occurs through the input of electrical energy and the voltage required to do this (decomposition potential) can be calculated from the Nernst Equation. So we can actually REVERSE a naturally occurring reaction with electricity

Comment: This is probably a government secret in my opinion as to this day the physics behind bonding is not available to the public and computational chemistry programs are typically only concerned with predicting molecular orbitals, IR frequencies and partial charges over and over and over again

Answer (score 1):

Chemical reactions occur when a chemical's covalent bonds are broken and new covalent bonds are formed.  This is a different situation than electricity flowing through a conductor.  For common conductors such as copper, there is approximately one "free" electron per atom that can move through the conductor, and this electron is not bound to any one particular atom of copper.  Because of this, an electric field in the conductor causes this electron to move opposite the direction of the electric field, but no covalent bonds are broken or made as this happens.  As a result, no chemical reaction takes place.

Comment: The breaking and forming of bonds isn't confined to covalent bonds: ionic bonds may also be involved (think e.g. the reduction of ionic metal oxides by other 'more reactive' metals)

Comment: I'm well aware of that, Gert.  I chose to use the most common example.

Comment: Very well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For a chemical reaction to occur, you must produce a different chemical substance through the process.  With electron flow, metal atoms are losing and gaining electrons at the same rate.  Also, metallic bonded atoms form mixtures (or consist of single elements), rather than compounds.  Arguably, their are transient ions produced, consider charging an electroscope by contact-there are additional, or fewer electrons around some of the atoms some of the time and ionization should be considered to be a chemical change both conceptually and energetically, but what constitutes a chemical change is largely tautological: If it's a chemical change then what you have is a new substance; if what you have is a new substance then it was a chemical change.  On a molar level, and over time, a wire does not become a new substance, though again, IONIZATION IS strictly speaking a chemical change so on the atomic scale moving electrons IS a transient chemical process, similar to dissolving salts at equilibrium.

Answer (score 1):

Chemical reactions do indeed occur with electron movement, not in wires but in chemical systems specially designed to collect up the electrons involved and harness their capacity to perform work. Such a device is called an *electrochemical cell* or a *battery* and this field of study is called *electrochemistry*.

In the battery inside a cell phone, for example, chemical reactions take place which transfer electrons from one chemical element or molecule to another. Those reactions are set up in such a way that those electrons are forced to flow through wires from the site of one reaction which liberates them to another site where they are consumed to complete the chemical reaction.

We can then use that electron flow to power our flashlights, computers, cell phones and MP3 players.